# GROUP BY query not ordering as expected

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by

I don't know why I can't make this query work the way I want, I hope you can enlighten me.

```
   SELECT e.id,
          e.num,
          e.name,
          s.name as s_name,
          t.num as t_num,
          e.show_id  
     FROM s_episodes e  
LEFT JOIN shows s ON s.id = e.show_id  
LEFT JOIN s_seasons t ON t.id = e.season_id  
 GROUP BY e.show_id  
 ORDER BY e.dateadded DESC
```

dateadded is an int (unix timepost). e.num, t.num are also int.

Is is supposed to show the latest episodes added, but when the GROUP BY groups the rows, the episodes listed aren't the latest ones but the first episode (episode number indicated by e.num) of the latest season (season number indicated by t_num) of a show (however, shows are ordered by dateadded based on the latest episodes, but the episode listed is the first one of the season, not the last added).

Any ideas?

I hope I made myself clear, sorry for any english mistakes. Thanks.

Comment: crazy mysql!, that statement should throw an error about *e.id, e.num,e.name, s.name,* and *t.num* not being part of the group by or an aggergate function.

Comment: I don't understand why you want the `GROUP BY` clause - [mysql allows the group by to omit columns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html).  Do you only want to see a list of the most recently added episode per show?

Comment: help me with the logic: every season have x episodes... so what is the show element?....... 2. left join, left join - feels like losing something... then again I need to understand what u r after

Comment: I want the shows not to repeat. So if the 3 latest episodes are from the same show, only the last episode will appear, while showing latest episodes of other shows. So for LIMIT 10 for e.g, we have 10 different shows with their respective last episodes listed.

Comment: Asaf, the logic would be: 3 tables, one contains the shows (e.g. Lost, The Big Bang Theory, and info about them), another contains all the seasons for that show (with info of each season and year of emission), and the other contains each episode info, which have to refer to a season (season_id) and a show (show_id).

Comment: The latest show is based on the highest `S_EPISODE.num` value, per `S_EPISODE.show_id` value?

Comment: Not necessarily OMG Ponies, sometimes the latest episode created is not the one with the highest s_episode.num, but with the highest s_episode.dateadded, that's why I want to order it by dateadded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you group by by one field and the resulting field is not a part of it (or in your case the order by field) the outcome is unpredictable.

You need to either add it to group by
or in your case, use aggregate function:

```
ORDER BY MAX(e.dateadded) DESC
```

**EDIT**: 
do you really need the `LEFT JOIN`s or those could aswell be regular inner joins?

Since you need also to to display the fields from latest episode you may try:

```
   SELECT e.id,
          e.num,
          e.name,
          s.name as s_name,
          t.num as t_num,
          e.show_id  
     FROM shows s
     JOIN s_episodes e ON e.id = 
              (SELECT id 
                 FROM s_episodes 
                WHERE show_id = s.id 
                ORDER BY dateadded DESC LIMIT 1)
LEFT JOIN s_seasons t ON t.id = e.season_id  
 ORDER BY e.dateadded DESC
```

Comment: +1. To speed up the query, it would be good to create an index on `s_episodes (show_id, dateadded, id)` and change the subquery ordering clause to `ORDER BY show_id DESC, dateadded DESC, id DESC`. This may seem redundant, but it is required for `MySQL` to pick up the correct index.

Comment: @Quassnoi: Thank you. It's very clerver

Answer (score 0):

you need to first determine the most recent episode added for the given show.  Then you can add the rest of the data.

```
SELECT a.dateadded,
      e.id, 
          e.num, 
          e.name, 
          s.name as s_name, 
          t.num as t_num, 
          e.show_id   

from          
(select max(dateadded) maxdate, show_id
     FROM s_episodes 
     group by show_id)a
inner join s_episodes e
      on e.show_id = a.show_id
      and e.dateadded = a.maxdate
LEFT JOIN shows s ON s.id = e.show_id   
LEFT JOIN s_seasons t ON t.id = e.season_id
```